# Assistance for query for duplicates

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates

I have a query that gives me all [N_SINISTRO] duplicated, now from this query I need to present all the duplicates of [N_SINISTRO] where [ID_UTILIZADOR] is different.

```
SELECT listagem.N_SINISTRO, listagem.ID, listagem.N_SUBSINCOGEN, listagem.ID_UTILIZADOR, listagem.Utilizador, listagem.Equipa, listagem.[Tipo Viatura], listagem.Situação, listagem.[Cod Postal], listagem.Concelho, listagem.[Estatuto Ofic], listagem.Rede, listagem.Oficina, listagem.DATA_ENTREGA, listagem.DATA_VENDA
FROM listagem
WHERE (((listagem.N_SINISTRO) In (SELECT [N_SINISTRO] FROM [listagem] As Tmp
                                  GROUP BY [N_SINISTRO]
                                  HAVING Count(*)>1 ))
  AND ((listagem.DATA_VENDA) Between [Forms]![menu]![Text1] And [Forms]![menu]![Text3]))
ORDER BY listagem.N_SINISTRO;
```

That's what the query gives me.

```
[N_SINISTRO] [ID_UTILIZADOR]
Y             X
Y             X
Y             N
```

These are the values you need.

```
[N_SINISTRO] [ID_UTILIZADOR]
Y             X
Y             N
```

Comment: Simply do `SELECT DISTINCT`? (Your query selects many columns, but your example result has only two columns. Too simplified?)

Comment: Yes, it was only to simplify

Comment: How can I use the, `SELECT DISTINCT`? @jarlh

Comment: Your code is invalid SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: It is from MSACCESS

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in MS Access using `GROUP BY`.  However, your output has three columns but your query has many more, so I'm not sure of the exact syntax.

For the output you specify, the `GROUP BY` would be:

```
GROUP BY N_SINISTRO, ID_UTILIZADOR
```

However, these would have to be the only columns in the `SELECT`.

Comment: For this query he already group by ID_UTILIZADOR but fails to show just duplicates of N_SINISTRO. `SELECT listagem.N_SINISTRO, listagem.ID_UTILIZADOR
FROM listagem
GROUP BY listagem.N_SINISTRO, listagem.ID_UTILIZADOR
HAVING (((listagem.N_SINISTRO) In (SELECT [N_SINISTRO] FROM [listagem] As Tmp GROUP BY [N_SINISTRO] HAVING Count(*)>1 )));`